# Oracle SQL: Merge two results in 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently creating a SQL query to get the results of all records from two tables that are connected via ID. Is there anyway to return the results in 1 row if there are multiple records link to 1 id from a different table? Below are my SQL query, current result and what is the expected result of the query.

Current query:

```
SELECT
    'A' AS "actionIndicator", 'A' AS "target",      
    crdExpt.CRD_PAN,
    acnExpt.ACN_ATP_ID, acnExpt.ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
FROM 
    tbl1 crdExpt, tbl2 acnExpt, tbl3 crdAcnExpt
```

where `tbl1` is the record for card numbers, `tbl2` is the record for account numbers and `tbl3` is where the linking of card and account numbers.

Current result is like this:

```
CRD_PAN   | ACN_ATP_ID| ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
123456789 | 23        | 99112345678
123456789 | 24        | 99012345678
```

What I'm trying to achieve is if there 2 account numbers linked to 1 card, the expected output is:

```
CRD_PAN   | ACN_ATP_ID| ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER |ACN_ATP_ID2 | ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER2
123456789 | 23        | 99112345678        | 24         | 99012345678
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Do you need separate columns, or could they be in the same column?

Comment: @JerryM. should be on separate column just like the expected output.

Comment: OK. I have a solution to have the results in the SAME column, but I cannot find a solution for separate columns, sorry.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, will take note on this. thanks!

Comment: @JerryM. can you please share your solution, sir?

Comment: have a look at `pivot` for Oracle's SQL.

Comment: Is a number of accounts linked to the card are restricted to 2 or it may be more or less?

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 yes. can be more or less 2

Answer (score 1):

By OP request in the comments:

I used the following example data (the result of your query) on [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de5573/5)

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  CRD_PAN VARCHAR(256),
  ACN_ATP_ID VARCHAR(256),
  ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(256)
 );

 INSERT INTO test(CRD_PAN, ACN_ATP_ID, ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
 SELECT '123456789', '23', '99112345678' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '123456789', '24', '99012345678' FROM DUAL
 ;
```

From there, I ran the following query:

```
SELECT
  CRD_PAN,
  LISTAGG(ACN_ATP_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CRD_PAN) AS ACN_ATP_ID,
  LISTAGG(ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CRD_PAN) AS ACN_ATP_ID

 FROM
   test

 GROUP BY
   CRD_PAN
```

Which gave me:

```
|  CRD_PAN  | ACN_ATP_ID |        ACN_ATP_ID       |
|:---------:|:----------:|:-----------------------:|
| 123456789 |   23, 24   | 99012345678,99112345678 |
```

So, I believe a solution could be:

```
WITH 

    test AS (

        SELECT
          'A' AS "actionIndicator", 'A' AS "target",        
          crdExpt.CRD_PAN,
          acnExpt.ACN_ATP_ID, acnExpt.ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        FROM tbl1 crdExpt, tbl2 acnExpt, tbl3 crdAcnExpt
    ),

    listdata AS (
        SELECT
            CRD_PAN,
            LISTAGG(ACN_ATP_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CRD_PAN) AS ACN_ATP_ID,
            LISTAGG(ACN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CRD_PAN) AS ACN_ATP_ID

        FROM
            test

        GROUP BY
            CRD_PAN
    )

SELECT * FROM listdata
```

The `LISTAGG` function allows you to move multiple rows into one, separated by some sort of character (I used `,`), and a subquery was used to demonstrate capturing your data, aggregating it, and then returning it